# React onClick() doesn't trigger when inside map function

Tags: reactjs, onclick

I'm building my first react application and I've got an issue.

I want to create a simple app where I can click on a book title in a sidebar, and see a summary of the book. I'm getting the book titles and summaries through an API I've defined locally.

Right now, clicking on a book title doesn't do anything. I get an error in red in the console:

```
index.js:1 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
```

I'm calling my API like so:

```
  const [viewingId, setViewingId] = useState()
  const [bookList, setBookList] = useState([])
  const [contents, setContents] = useState({})

  useEffect(() => {

    fetch("http://localhost:5000/books")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {setBookList(res)})
  }, [])

  const fetchBookSummary = (id) => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:5000/book/${id}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
      setContents({...contents, [id]: res[0]})
    })
  }
```

This is how I'm defining my 'onClick' function:

```
  const seeSummary = (id) => {
    fetchBookSummary(id)
    setViewingId(id)
  }
```

And finally, my App renders like this:

```
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="App-Container">
        <div className="BookList">
          {bookList.map(book => (
            <Node book={book} onClick={() => seeSummary(book.id)} />
          ))}
        </div>

        <div className="SummaryView">
          {contents[viewingId]?.content?.map((summaryData => (
              <Summary summaryData={summaryData}/>
          )))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I used to have just `onClick={seeSummary(book.id)}`, but I got a "too many re-renders" error...I'm not sure I understand what adding `() =>` did.

I'd like to be able to see the Summary when I click on a book. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To resolve the React key warning you just need to provide a valid React key to the elements being mapped.

```
{bookList.map(book => (
  <Node
    key={book.id} // <-- Add a unique key, the book id is good
    book={book}
    onClick={() => seeSummary(book.id)}
  />
))}
```

When you were just `onClick={seeSummary(book.id)}` this was invoking the callback immediately, thus causing the render looping. By adding the "() =>" you are declaring an anonymous function to invoke your `seeSummary` function and pass the specific book id *at-the-time* the node is clicked.

I don't see any overt issues with the way you've defined your onClick handler other than the fetching book details will take longer than it will take to update the summary id.

```
const seeSummary = (id) => {
  fetchBookSummary(id); // fetching data
  setViewingId(id); // will update first.
}
```

I suspect you haven't connected/attached the `onClick` prop of the `Node` component to any DOM element, like a `button` or `div`, etc... You need to ensure that the `onClick` prop is *actually* attached to *something* a user can interact with.

Example:

```
const Node = ({ book, onClick }) => (
  <div onClick={onClick}>
    {book.title} - Click me to see summary!
  </div>
);
```